# Change input css in function of the length of its value

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make an if statement in JS that is dependent on character count in an html input field? For example, if there is a value greater than 0 in the input field then css attributes of that field will change.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending if you want it to happen on page load or checking while something changes in the input field. On page load check [@gurvinder372 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664025/how-do-i-make-an-if-statement-in-js-that-is-dependent-on-character-count-in-an-h/36664055#36664055) else you can check this for `onkeyup` on the input field:

```js
document.getElementById('input').onkeyup = function(){
     if(this.value.length > 0) {
       this.style.background = 'red';
     } else {
       this.style.background = 'green';
     }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<input type="text" id="text1">
```

and js code `if` condition as

```
document.onload = function(){
  var val = document.getElementById("text1").value;
  var characterCount = 10;
  if ( val.length > characterCount )
  {
    //Now the character count is greater than 10
    document.getElementById("text1").style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

And to complete the list of answers, now one answer that evaluates the value when the input loses focus.

```js
function inputChange(value) {
 window.txt.style.color = value > 3 ? 'red' : 'blue';
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" onchange="inputChange(this.value)" />
```